# problem with image registration using BRISK

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, feature-descriptor, feature-matching

i am using BRISK to extract feature from remote sensing images but the extracted feature are not right [the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EK8u.jpg)
the code on matlab is as follows:

```
original1 = imread('im1.tif');
ptsOriginalBRISK1  = detectBRISKFeatures(original1,'MinContrast',0.01,'MinQuality',0.7);
[featuresO1,validPtsO1]  =  extractFeatures(original1,ptsOriginalBRISK1);
distorted1 = imread('im2.tif');
ptsDistortedBRISK1 = detectBRISKFeatures(distorted1,'MinContrast',0.01,'MinQuality',0.7);
[featuresD1,validPtsD1] = extractFeatures(distorted1,ptsDistortedBRISK1);
Pairs11 = matchFeatures(featuresO1,featuresD1,'MatchThreshold',90,'MaxRatio',0.9);
matchedO  = validPtsO1(Pairs11(:,1));
matchedD = validPtsD1(Pairs11(:,2));
[tform, inlierDistorted,inlierOriginal] = estimateGeometricTransform(matchedD,matchedO,'similarity');
figure
showMatchedFeatures(original1,distorted1,inlierOriginal,inlierDistorted,'montage')
title('Matching points (inliers only)')
legend('im1','im2')
```

as you can see the features extracted is not right

Comment: the plot is very low-res.

Comment: the low -res is the reason the wrong feature matching ? it is a big image  and i took a piece of it, do i need to take larger piece? or smaller?

Comment: most likely the images don't look anything alike. try matching their brightnesses and contrasts. manually (photo editor) if you need to. see if that helps. -- yes, low res is useless. I have to assume that your screenshot represents all the resolution you have. if you have more, you would have shared it by now. [mre]

Comment: the two images are to the same region it is taken by longitudes and latitudes  lines but the resolution is different and i want to wrap the one image to the other without losing any information or changing the brightness of any image